# setup elasticsearch cluster on aks azure using terraform

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am looking for guidance on setting up Elasticsearch 1 master & 1 data nodes on Azure Kubernetes Service using terraform I have setup a cluster and want to do automatically deploy Elasticsearch 6 during AKS Cluster creation is there possible way out ? I did some google but couldn't get it.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you know how to install the Elasticsearch via helm in Kubernetes?

Comment: no i don't have idea about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the Elasticsearch in AKS through the Helm. Follow the steps [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html) to create the AKS via Terraform. And use the [Helm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs) via the Terraform. [Here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/2082#issuecomment-433187629) is an example that installs the Helm chart in AKS via Terraform. [Here](https://vocon-it.com/2019/03/04/kubernetes-9-installing-elasticsearch-using-helm-charts/) is also an example that installs Elasticsearch in AKS via Helm.